# How to set manually the number of an item in embedded list

Tags: lists

In a simple list in order to set the number of an item the following code is enough :

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \setcounter{enumi}{4}
  \item fifth element
\end{enumerate}
```

It displays `5. fifth element`

However I want to display `2a. This element`

How can I do that ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: Please a have look on the documentation of the `enumitem` package for an easy configuration of such a feature

Comment: There is actually more than one way, but the easy one it \item[2a].

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I don't have any code yet which does not work. I am just trying to figure out a way to put a constant value (2a) in front of a listing item.